# Sqlite flutter app work on Android emuator but not on IOS emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

Hi i have followed a youtube tutorial and made a sqlite app that works on android emulator perfectly but when i try to run on ios emulator i get the following error message:

Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on Iphone 13.

My database helper file:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;

class SQLHelper {
  //method to create table
  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE sets(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      exercise_name TEXT,
      total_weight TEXT,
      total_reps TEXT,
      date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      )
      """);
  }

//method to open the database called db
  static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    return sql.openDatabase('dbsets.db', version: 1,
        onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
      print('Creating Table');
      await createTables(database); //calling that create table method above
    });
  }

//method to create an item to insert into the database table
  static Future<int> createItem(
    String exercise_name,
    String? total_weight,
    String? total_reps,
  ) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //opening the database
    final data = {
      'exercise_name': exercise_name,
      'total_weight': total_weight,
      'total_reps': total_reps,
      'date': DateTime.now().toString()
    }; //making map to insert
    final id = await db.insert(
        //inserting that data map
        'sets',
        data, //items is table name and data is the map we made
        conflictAlgorithm: sql
            .ConflictAlgorithm.replace); //best practice to prevent duplicates
    return id;
  }

//this will return a list of maps
//gets called when app is launched and will get all our shit from the database
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItems() async {
    //getItems will be a List
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    return db.query('sets', orderBy: "id");
  }

//method for getting 1 item from the database based on id
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItem(int id) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query('sets',
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id], limit: 1); //limit 1 means get only 1
  }

  //UPDATING AN ENTRY
  static Future<int> updateItem(
    int id,
    String exercise_name,
    String? total_weight,
    String? total_reps,
  ) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    final data = {
      'exercise_name': exercise_name,
      'total_weight': total_weight,
      'total_reps': total_reps,
      'date': DateTime.now().toString()
    }; //

    final result =
        await db.update('sets', data, where: "id= ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    return result;
  }

  //Deleting an Entry
  static Future<void> deleteItem(int id) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    try {
      await db.delete("sets", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    } catch (err) {
      debugPrint("Something went wrong when deleting an item: $err");
    }
  }
}
```

and my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:labud_fit_concept/sql_helper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //creating a list of maps
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _sets = [];

  bool _isLoading = true;

  //this method will store everything from out database in data
  void _refreshSets() async {
    final data = await SQLHelper.getItems(); //getItems returns a list of maps
    setState(() {
      _sets = data;
      _isLoading = false; //finished loading
    });
  }

  //now to call this refreshJournals method
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _refreshSets();
    print("number of sets: ${_sets.length}");
  }

  final TextEditingController _exercisenameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _totalweightController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _totalrepsController = TextEditingController();

  void _showForm(int? id) async {
    if (id != null) {
      // id == null -> create new item
      // id != null -> update an existing item
      final existingSet = _sets.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == id);
      _exercisenameController.text = existingSet['exercise_name'];
      _totalweightController.text = existingSet['total_weight'];
      _totalrepsController.text = existingSet['total_reps'];
    }
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 5,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (_) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15,
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                // this will prevent the soft keyboard from covering the text fields
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 120,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _exercisenameController,
                    decoration:
                        const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Exercise Name'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _totalweightController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Weight'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _totalrepsController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Reps'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    //button to confirm entry
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // Save new journal
                      if (id == null) {
                        //if the item doesnt exist
                        await _addItem();
                      }

                      if (id != null) {
                        //if it exists update it instead
                        await _updateItem(id);
                      }

                      // Clear the text fields
                      _exercisenameController.text = '';
                      _totalweightController.text = '';
                      _totalrepsController.text = '';

                      //closing the popup
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    //the text of the button change depending on if its new or updating an existing
                    child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
  }

// Insert a new journal to the database
  Future<void> _addItem() async {
    await SQLHelper.createItem(_exercisenameController.text,
        _totalweightController.text, _totalrepsController.text);
    _refreshSets(); //getting all of our database calls again
    print("number of journals: ${_sets.length}");
  }

  // Update an existing journal
  Future<void> _updateItem(int id) async {
    await SQLHelper.updateItem(id, _exercisenameController.text,
        _totalweightController.text, _totalrepsController.text);
    _refreshSets();
  }

  // Delete an item
  void _deleteItem(int id) async {
    await SQLHelper.deleteItem(id);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Successfully deleted a Set!'),
    ));
    _refreshSets();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          //so its a listview so we use our _journals list to build it
          itemCount: _sets.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 129, 142, 255),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: CupertinoListTile(
                  title: Text(_sets[index]['exercise_name']),
                  subtitle: Text(_sets[index]['total_weight']),
                  trailing: SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => _showForm(_sets[index]['id']),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => _deleteItem(_sets[index]['id']),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _showForm(null),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on iOS app development but I will try to provide a general troubleshooting:

1. **Clean and rebuild the project**: As with any project, sometimes cached data or outdated builds can cause issues. Try manually removing the application from your iOS emulator, rebooting the emulator and then cleaning and rebuilding your project by running the `flutter clean` command, followed by the `flutter build ios` command.
2. **Check the database path**: Verify that the path to the database file you are using is correct. In iOS, the app's file system is sandboxed, and the file paths to access the app's file system are different than on Android. Make sure that you are using the correct file path based on the platform you are running your app on.
3. **Debugging**: If none of the above steps work, you can use Xcode's debugger to step through your code and see where the issue is occurring. You can set breakpoints in your code and then run the app in debug mode to step through your code and see where the error is occurring.